# how to display multiple table base on user login name

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 table and more but i want to use another table base on user name login in php mysql so this my table

**content Table**

```
kode_content    |  judul_content  | kode_user | deskripsi  |  nama_lengkap
   2                  abc              1           tes1        john
   3                  efg              2           tes2        gerald
   4                  hij              1           tes3        john
```

**user table**

```
kode_user  |  username   |  password  | nama_lengkap
  1            user1          123         john 
  2            user2          234        gerald
```

and i want to display content table from session login username i dont know how to explain cause i newbie so When user login with username above and show judul_content, deskripsi, nama_lengkap base on user login nama_lengkap another judul_content don't show, for example
user login with username above with name gerald and this output i want :

**output**

```
judul_content   |  deskripsi   | nama_lengkap
   efg               tes2          gerald
```

**function.php**

```
function get_content($where = ""){
        $koneksi = connection();
        $data = mysql_query("select content.*, user.judul_content,user.nama_lengkap from content inner join user on content.kode_user = user.kode_user ") or die ("query error");
        destroy_connection($koneksi);
        return to_array($data);
    }
```

i try to use content.kode_user = '$user'; but not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query is incorrect. Try the following query:

```
$data = mysql_query("select content.*  
from content 
inner join user on content.kode_user = user.kode_user
where user.kode_user = $user;") or die ("query error");
```

or even better and simpler:

```
$data = mysql_query("select * from content kode_user = $user;") or die ("query error");
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: user in

Comment: As per the opening question $user supposed to hold current logged in user's ID based on session. Make sure $user holds logged-in user's ID before executing the sql code.

Comment: ok i just solved this question and now i have another problem with my query i have to change my table or add some thanks for answer

Comment: but i don't use your answer above i use based my query.. should i checklist ? cause i'm new here